# I want to create an empty bitmap in directx, draw a picture and then output it

Tags: c++, directx-11

The result of all function calls is S_OK.
I was expecting a blue square to appear on the screen.
But it's just a black screen.
I am newbie to directx.
I'm not sure what the problem is. T_T
Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding or missing a procedure..

this is my code.

****draw.cpp****

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> pBlackBrush;
m_deviceContext->CreateSolidColorBrush(
    D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Blue),
    &pBlackBrush
);

D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES newBitmapProperties =
    D2D1::BitmapProperties(
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
        96,
        96
    );

m_deviceContext->SetTarget(m_d2dTargetBitmap.Get());

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IWICBitmap> newWicBitmap;

auto ret3 = m_wicFactory->CreateBitmap(300, 300, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPRGBA, WICBitmapCacheOnDemand, newWicBitmap.GetAddressOf());


D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES m_RenderTargetProp = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();

m_RenderTargetProp.dpiX = 96;
m_RenderTargetProp.dpiY = 96;
m_RenderTargetProp.minLevel = D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT;
m_RenderTargetProp.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED);
m_RenderTargetProp.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
m_RenderTargetProp.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> bitmapRender;

auto ret2 = pD2DFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(newWicBitmap.Get(), m_RenderTargetProp, bitmapRender.GetAddressOf());

if (ret2 != S_OK)
    OutputDebugString(L"BitmapRenderTarget Error\n");

bitmapRender->BeginDraw();

D2D1_RECT_F f{ 0,0,200,200 };

bitmapRender->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(
    0,
    0,
    100.0f,
    100.0f), pBlackBrush.Get());

bitmapRender->EndDraw();

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> newBitmap;
ret3 = bitmapRender->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(newWicBitmap.Get(), newBitmap.GetAddressOf());

m_deviceContext->BeginDraw();
m_deviceContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black));

m_deviceContext->DrawBitmap(newBitmap.Get());
m_deviceContext->EndDraw();

DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters{ 0, };
m_swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &parameters);
```

Comment: Difficult to follow. Do you have a small reproducing sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I thought this was a very minimal code. May I know what kind of smaller code you want?

Comment: a whole small project that reproduces your problem

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
When I set the bitmap creation to deviceContext , it was solved.